# Can the acronym package be told to use a certain style?

Tags: formatting, acronyms, italic

I'm using the [`acronym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package and I'm trying to add generic styling. Specifically, I want the first mention of the acronym to expand the long form in italics.

What I've done so far is to say:

```
\acrodef{label}[short]{\textit{long form}}
```

And that seems to work as long as you don't need to *repeat* the long form (which I don't). However it clashes when you need the plural form `\acp{lable}`, as the plural "s" will not be typeset in italics:

> *long form*s <- wrong
>   *long forms* <- correct

Is there a way to tell the acronym package to typeset the long form in italics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\acffont}[1]{\textit{#1}}
```

sets the font of the entire full expression, including the long form, parentheses and acronym. In order to *only* make the long form italics, one has to override the italic mode for the remainder of the full expression by adding:

```
\renewcommand*{\acfsfont}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I *just* found this, too. However, I cannot get the long form to be set in italics, but not the part in parentheses: That is, I want "*long form:* (short)" instead of "*long form (short)*" but `\acffont` seems to encompass the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it hasn't been included back then, but the package comes with different styles already (see the [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/acronym)). So no need to renewcommand.

To write out the acronym in cursive/italics, one should use `\acfi{AI}` instead of the `\ac{AI}`-command.
However, using `\acfi` will result in every usage of the acronym to be written out with the long form as well.